# Building a multi-location app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I am trying to build a multi-location app from a client. I have tried dabbling with Apartment and other types of multitenancy but didn't receive a proper result.

The app should have domains for each location as follows:

**e.g. example.com/newyork, example.com/boston**

I can't use subdomains, as they will be used for languages.

**e.g. en.example.com/newyork, es.example.com/newyork**

Each location will have a model showing content and search functionality for that location only.

**e.g. When in newyork, boston posts won't be shown and when in boston, new york posts won't be shown.**

However, a user has a single sign-on for all locations and languages, and a user can view all content posted within the app regardless of the location. If I use multitenancy, the user can only view New York posts when on /newyork and Boston posts when on /boston which is not the desired result.

What approach should I follow here? Does multitenancy even make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Why you do mot want to add it to params? You will make url like `www.mysite.com/en/boston` or `mysite.com/es/madrid`

And you will make some default locale, where you'll load if no locale found in params.

As s simple example try out https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage part about localization, it is very good example